# Python, Ubuntu and GStreamer - specifying one of two webcams

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, pygtk, webcam

Using the initial code from this question, I can get a live window from a webcam.

[Taking a snapshot from webcam monitor in python (pygtk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324908/taking-a-snapshot-from-webcam-monitor-in-python-pygtk)

I have two webcams on my system, and I want to specify which camera I am calling for the viewer.

I have been poking around, and with nothing connected I get this error:

```
Error: Resource not found. v4l2_calls.c(493): gst_v4l2_open (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
system error: No such file or directory
```

This suggests to me that I can probably tell the streamer to look at another pipeline... perhaps `/GstPipeline:pipeline1/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0` or `/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src1`

My ubuntu foo is not that good, and I'm not sure how I might specify which camera to use. I suspect that there is something in this line I can change:

```
 self.player = gst.parse_launch ("v4l2src ! autovideosink")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly did you try so far? Also `gst_parse_launch` is rather a dev tool then an API...

Comment: @drahnr I have no idea where to start! hence posting a question. I',m not sure if its a python problem or a nix problem. I know roughly what I think I need to do, I just don't know where to look for guidance to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each camera should create device `/dev/videoN` (where N is a number, TV cards and old GeForce cards with a Tuner will also create devices as `/dev/videoN` but these are false friends)

```
v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! autovideosink
```

should work, where `device=` specifies which devices to pick as input src.

Alsp have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787967/capturing-h-264-stream-from-camera-with-gstreamer)

---

Keep in mind that this is not a clean approach - `gst_parse_launch` is a devtool and can not change settings dynamically (i.e. volume level, brightness etc - these are fixed for the lifetime of the stream)

Comment: Ahh, Thank you. I didn't realise it was possible to pass the name of the pipe being used. Thanks. The project is quick and dirty. The video will be in a mostly closed system with fixed illumination. I have looked at opencv as a better solution, but struggled to get it to compile. Thank you, thats a great help. And the link is an excellent resource and is answering many of my questions.